# Login system for android app and online-server

Tags: android, client, server, user-management

He,

I recently develop an app that stores user based data on an server. Now I want that users can register for the app and then only can edit there data on the server. 
Is there a good tutorial out there that shows how to develop such a system ?

Gruß, Andre

Comment: Not sure if i understand you all right, but you can read about cloud computing. There are sites like www.cloudmine that give you  free server database for your apps.You store, edit and read data from it.

Answer (score 0):

its more of a conceptual thing than that of a tutorial... break down the life cycle of the whole login and registration stuff and try to implement each step... once registration is done think of the way how your will identify request coming from each user best example is most website use use cookies and verify on the server does that user have to right to edit that content.